# How do I clear the console in a Lua Program

Tags: lua, console

I'm making my first Lua program with the console, and I need to find out how to remove all the text in the console without just appending a ton of \n's.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `os.execute()`.

On Windows:

```
os.execute("cls")
```

On Unix:

```
os.execute("clear")
```

Answer (score 6):

If your console understands ANSI terminal escape sequences, try `io.write("\027[H\027[2J")`.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the other reply, you can use *os.execute()* to clear the console. However, if you do not have access to this function, then you might be forced to spam the console with new lines, so it seems "empty" to the user.

**However, if you are able to use os.execute, then you should definitely use it.**

```
for i = 1, 255 do
    print()
end
```

Comment: Clever, very clever.

Comment: it  spam \n's when OP didn't ask something that spam \n's

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late answer, but if anyone check this post here's a way to do it :

```
if not os.execute("clear") then
    os.execute("cls")
elseif not os.execute("cls") then
    for i = 1,25 do
        print("\n\n")
    end
end
```

This will work on any os.

Comment: I think it will never run `elseif` branch.

Comment: also the code work incorrectly it spam new lines when i have 'clear' command
you havent test it right on multiple OSes?