# How to clear multi-line command in Lua interpreter?

Tags: lua

For example, if I'm writing a multiline command in Python, I can just press `ctrl-c`.

In Lua, for one liners, I could press `ctrl-u` to clear a single line, but that doesn't do anything for multi-line functions, etc. `ctrl-c` in Lua quits the interpreter.

Edit:
As an example say I'm writing a function in Lua:

```
>> function Test()
..> print 'Test'
..> e
```

At this point, I'm about to write `end` and I realize I didn't want to call the function `Test()`, rather I wanted to call it `Test123()`, how would I break out of this like with Python's `ctrl-c`?

Comment: check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187310/how-do-i-clear-the-console-in-a-lua-program

Comment: I saw that, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to know if I'm typing a command in the interpreter, how would I skip that line and go to a new line, not clear the screen.

Answer (score 3):

You can always type ';', which will terminate the current command. You will get a syntax error in this case (as the statement is not complete), but you can then use parts of your command for a new command.

Answer (score 1):

Even when Lua is reading multiline statements, it is reading it line by line by calling `readline`. The effect is that you can only edit the current line, not the whole multiline.

The same thing seems to happen in Python (when multiline statements are signaled by a `\` continuation). However, Python seems to handle `ctrl-c` different from Lua: it somehow catches `ctrl-c` and returns to the prompt, whereas Lua has not signal handler for `ctrl-c` set during input and so aborts the program, which is the default action.